# Sails JS: How to create model objects from the result of .query()?

Tags: sails.js

I need to retrieve a set of records that require a somewhat complex criteria with multiple joins. I can get the records I want by doing a .query() with my own SQL. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to turn those records into actual model instances with instance methods, etc. I'm sure there's some kind of an internal method available to create a model instance from a record that's already been retrieved that I just need to map my results to, I just don't know what it is.

Some help?

Comment: How about just running Model.find() on the resulting IDs.

Comment: That isn't a good solution because it's potentially joining a large record set - which ends up having to send a lot of data from the DB, serializing it, the sending it back to the DB in a second query - very inefficient and might also hit query size limit issues in certain drivers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Collection._model(jsObject).

I know there was talk of an effort to make this an official public api, rather than a "hidden" option using a supposedly private method.

Example:

```
new Pet._model({name: "fluffy"});
```

See this [issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/763) for details. Btw, particlebanana (Cody Stoltman) who recommended this option in that issue is the lead developer on waterline ORM. Hopefully that gives you some confidence.